# Excel: formatting dates in plain text to date format

Tags: excel

I'm having an issue trying to format some cells to recognize some plain text dates in the following formats:

8 April 1992
December 15, 1986

Is there any solution to this issue?, I whould do it manually, however, there are about 700+ rows of data.

I already tried setting the format of each cell(fortunately all data is all clustered in date formats), but no sucess at all.

I have Excel 2013

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You realize that you can copy a format from a single cell to a range of cells, right?

Comment: Yeah, however, Excel isn't recognizing the data in the cell as dates.

Comment: Then you're not copying the format correctly.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/q5dt00ckl/

Comment: An Excel formattable date is a numeric value, where the integer part represents days since 1970 or some such and the fractional part represents the fraction of the day.  Dates must be initially entered as formatted dates (and hence converted to numbers) to be reformattable.  But I think there is some Excel function that will convert a character date to numeric form (though I can't tell you how to use it).

Comment: @pnuts - If he has character strings in the cells I don't think the date format will have any real effect.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=IF(CODE(LEFT(A1))>64,VALUE(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,2)&" "&LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1))&RIGHT(A1,4)),A1)
```

I doubt it will fix all but maybe enough to make manual adjustment for the remainder viable - or at least identify what adjustment might be required!

Comment: Oh, no, is not showing the office date format numbers; it still showing the plain text dates...

Comment: Really weird indeed :S

Comment: I'll tokenize all data into columns, then transform each month into the serial number.

Comment: All data is from the web and my locale is dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: I used Text to Columns, I've been looking for the solution, however nothing comes up.